# How can I tell Vim to fold GEDCOM files?

Tags: vim, folding, levels, gedcom

GEDCOM files start with a level number 0,1,2, etc., e.g. `2 DATE 10 SEP 1843`. The GEDCOM syntax file does not support folding. It should take only a couple of colon commands to tell Vim that it should automatically assign the level number to the line's `foldlevel` so that `zM` displays only the level 0 lines, etc. Unfortunately my Vimscript skills are not up to it.

Comment: Although not off-topic here, note that there's [a dedicated sister-site for Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) where this question might get more attention.

Comment: The two lines are:   `set foldmethod=expr` and `set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)`, and they can be put inside `gedcom.vim`

Comment: That sounds like an answer :) See [can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Put these lines inside gedcom.vim:

```
set foldmethod=expr
foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)
```